# Gmail is ignoring display none

Tags: html, gmail

I am attempting to create separate mobile and desktop views for a section of an email.

Thus far I have a min-width 499px section of the CSS for desktop and a max-width 400px section for mobile

Desktop Queries:

```
adventures {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        font-size: 0px; 
        max-height:0;
        width: 0 !important;
        }

.hide1 {

        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        font-size: 0px; 
        max-height:0;
        width: 0 !important;
```

Mobile queries:

```
.adventuresMOB {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        font-size: 0px; 
        max-height:0;
        width: 0 !important;
        }

.hide2 {

        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        font-size: 0px; 
        max-height:0;
        width: 0 !important;
```

I put the .adventure classes in the `<tr>` tags around the images and the .hide classes in `<div>` tags directly around the images.

It's working in every email client but the gmail.

Comment: Lots of email systems don't support css classes; all styles must be inline. It sucks, and would be poor practice anywhere else, but for e-mail it's what you gotta do.

Comment: Do you by chance know the format for an @media tag inline? such as: style="@media (max-width:400px){display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}"

Comment: I suggest checking some messages actually sent to you and see how they do it.